# Background color Graph Android

Tags: android, graph, background-color, achartengine

How can I change the background color of the graph in Android.
Meaning:  the background of the graph is black, and the graph itself is white, also the background of the activity is white. Can't seem to find where to change the black to white...

I can change the color of the Graph itself, but not the background on which it is displayed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Which library you are using to generate graph?

Comment: very confusing language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below methods to change colors

```
renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
renderer.setMarginsColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution, had to use `mRenderer.setMarginsColor` thanks for the answers!

Comment: if that is correct Answer .. should accept the answer. then only it helps others